# Draw partial box around text

Tags: boxes

I want to put text in a box where only two corners of the box are visible. I've explored using tikzpicture and a new md environment.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366712/border-in-a-box-frame-or-minipage for example

Comment: also see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385433/getting-a-partially-framed-mdframed