# Stacking boxes to decorate the corners of a framed box

Tags: mdframed

I am trying to decorate the corners of a framed box to achieve a result like the image below ... Any suggestions how to stack boxes like this? I am not exactly familiar with tikz, so I was trying to achieve something like this without it.

[image]

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366712/border-in-a-box-frame-or-minipage

Comment: ...or related ...https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385433/getting-a-partially-framed-mdframed

Comment: Thank you all ... Sorry for posting a duplicate question. I searched using many keywords, but it seems I couldn't find the right ones. Cheers!

Comment: @Kazumi In the meantime excuse me...you are a new contributor...and welcome in this community. Your question is not a duplicate but the links can help you. Wait :-) an answer.