# A long text done with mdframed overlapped on the gray rectangle done with Mathcha

Tags: tikz-pgf, mdframed, tools, overlap, mathcha

I have this code,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=Tikz]{mdframed}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300

%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp7242002605277424] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 219; blue, 219 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.75]  (123,25) -- (563.5,25) -- (563.5,276.71) -- (123,276.71) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp15046039100295516] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (563.5,276.71) -- (563.5,293) -- (514.51,293) -- (514.51,276.71) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp7536303834926936] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (563.5,214.37) -- (579.5,214.37) -- (579.5,293) -- (563.5,293) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp955510069108573] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (107,8.71) -- (123,8.71) -- (123,87.34) -- (107,87.34) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp2936063286787003] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (171.99,8.71) -- (171.99,25) -- (123,25) -- (123,8.71) -- cycle ;
% Text Node
\draw (196,121) node [anchor=north][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\Huge] [align=left] {Here text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

created with Mathcha. I want to put a rectangle created with mdframed into the gray rectangle. Is it possible? If I put into *Here text* an enviroment

```
\draw (196,121) node [anchor=north][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\Huge] [align=left] {\begin{mdframed} Here text \end{mdframed}};
```

done with `mdframed` I obtain many mistakes.

Related question: [Stacking boxes to decorate the corners of a framed box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576861/stacking-boxes-to-decorate-the-corners-of-a-framed-box)

Comment: If what you want is to remove the gray filling color, then delete `[fill={rgb, 255:red, 219; green, 219; blue, 219 }  ,fill opacity=1 ]` from the first `\draw`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Hi, I have improved the question to be more clear. I want put a long text done with mdframed overlapped on the gray rectangle.

Comment: Do you mind using `tcolorbox`, or want to stick to `mdframd`?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ No it is not important whether or not to use tcolorbox or mdframed. I know that mdframed is less complete than tcolorbox. Mine was just a curiosity if this solution of mine brings to a good way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `tcolorbox` attempt. Current limitation: output is not "responsible" if the `tcolorbox` is shorter than the specified height minus yshift of corner rectangles.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{hooks, skins}

\usepackage[pass, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\tcbset{
  corner rect xshift/.store in=\tcb@rect@xshift,
  corner rect yshift/.store in=\tcb@rect@yshift,
  corner rect width/.store in=\tcb@rect@wd,
  corner rect height/.store in=\tcb@rect@ht,
  % init
  corner rect xshift=3pt,
  corner rect yshift=3pt,
  corner rect width=1cm,
  corner rect height=1cm
}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{
  sharp corners,
  boxrule=.2mm,
  enhanced,
  #1,
  % adjust margins
  leftright skip=\tcb@rect@xshift,
  enlarge top by=\tcb@rect@yshift,
  enlarge bottom by=\tcb@rect@yshift,
  % draw filled squares
  interior code pre={
    \fill[black]
      ([shift={(-\tcb@rect@xshift,\tcb@rect@yshift)}]frame.north west) rectangle +(\tcb@rect@wd, -\tcb@rect@ht)
      ([shift={(\tcb@rect@xshift,-\tcb@rect@yshift)}]frame.south east) rectangle +(-\tcb@rect@wd, \tcb@rect@ht);
  }
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}[corner rect width=.5cm, corner rect yshift=5pt]
  \lipsum[2]
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(the outer most frame is the text body frame created by `\usepackage[pass, showframe]{geometry}`).

Comment: But with my mathcha code I can't use it? +1

Comment: @Sebastiano Guess you want to import tikz or general latex codes into Mathcha, am I right? Then it is currently not supported, according to [its doc](https://www.mathcha.io/documentation/). See sec. 11. Import from Latex, which says " - Support most of latex symbols using in MathJax, Latex will be parsed in scope of pair $ $ or $$ $$, any text ouside will be parsed as normal text.
 - It can not parse any Latex from Text Mode in this release" In short, Mathcha can only export drawings to tikz codes, but not in the reversed direction.

Answer (score 1):

- sorry, in this simple case I don't see any benefits to use `Mathcha` program and the `mdframed` package.
- Code for the box in pure TikZ is simple and short
- so, this answer doesn't solve your problem :-(, but generate desired result on different way:

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\tikzset{
    every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}
        } %set default line width to 0.75pt
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,
                    node distance=0pt,
every node/.append style = {draw, fill=gray!39,
                            minimum height=250, text width=450,
                            inner sep=25pt, align=left}
                    ]
% rectangle
\node (n) {\lipsum[11]};
%
\draw[line width=12pt]
    ([shift={(-0.5\pgflinewidth,-50pt)}] n.north west) |-
    ([shift={( 40pt, 0.5\pgflinewidth)}] n.north west) 
 
    ([shift={( 0.5\pgflinewidth, 50pt)}] n.south east) |-
    ([shift={(-40pt,-0.5\pgflinewidth)}] n.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Above solution try to reproduce shoed image in your question. However, it seems that you my looking for the following solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}
        } %set default line width to 0.75pt
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt,
every node/.append style = {draw, fill=gray!39,
                            minimum height=12pt, 
                            text width=\dimexpr\linewidth-66pt,
                            inner sep=25pt, align=left}
                    ]
% rectangle
\node (n) {\lipsum[11]};
%
\draw[line width=8pt]
    ([shift={(-0.5\pgflinewidth,-50pt)}] n.north west) |-
    ([shift={( 40pt, 0.5\pgflinewidth)}] n.north west) 
 
    ([shift={( 0.5\pgflinewidth, 50pt)}] n.south east) |-
    ([shift={(-40pt,-0.5\pgflinewidth)}] n.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very kind Zarko, I wanted to understand if with my code done with Mathcha it was compatible with mdframed or with tcolorbox. But I always appreciated the answers :-)....and I recommend: be careful with earthquakes and I am close to the people who have suffered this drama. I always wish you all the best and a better new year in a few hours.