# Label within multiple stackinsets

Tags: labels, counters, stackengine

For my thesis I wanted to put theorems in a special box, for which I have created a command `\specialbox` which utilizes `\stackinset`, such that I get a partial frame around the theorem. Credits to its design go to Steven B. Segletes, I found the design [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366712/border-in-a-box-frame-or-minipage). Below I have attached a picture which illustrates the design and the problem (see below) and further below I included the MWE.

The problem: for the design I have used `\stackinset` four times. As you can see in the picture below, we go from Theorem I and equation (1) to Theorem XVII and equation (17), i.e. both have increased with 16. I assume that's because every time `\stackinset` is used, the counter is increased unnecessarily, and in the case of four `\stackinset`s, the counter is increased by 2^4 = 16. Obviously, that's not what I wanted. Does anyone know of a way to solve this problem?

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

%%% Load packages
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%%% Define special box
% \specialbox{<rule width>}{<rule length hori>}{<rule length vert>}{<distance from text>}{<text>}
\newcommand{\specialbox}[5]{%
\stackinset{l}{}{t}{}{ \rule{#2}{#1} }{%
\stackinset{l}{}{t}{}{ \rule{#1}{#3} }{%
\stackinset{r}{-#1-#4}{b}{}{ \rule{#2}{#1} }{%
\stackinset{r}{-#1-#4}{b}{-#1-#4}{ \rule{#1}{#3} }{%
\hspace{\dimexpr #1+#4} \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-#4-#4-#1-#1}{
\vspace{\dimexpr #1+#4} #5}}}}}}

%%% Define counter
\newcounter{myThm}
\setcounter{myThm}{0}
\renewcommand*{\themyThm}{\Roman{myThm}}
\newcommand{\mythm}{ \refstepcounter{myThm} {\bfseries Theorem \themyThm.} }

\begin{document}

\specialbox{1.5pt}{35pt}{35pt}{10pt}{%
\mythm \\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. 
\begin{align}\label{eq}
\dot{x}(t) = f\big( t,x(t) \big)
\end{align}
Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. 
}

\vspace{30pt}

\specialbox{1.5pt}{35pt}{35pt}{10pt}{%
\mythm \\
Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus.
\begin{align}\label{eq}
\dot{y}(t) = g\big( t,y(t) \big)
\end{align}
Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the definition of `\specialbox`, save the argument into a stored `\parbox` prior to invoking the `\stackinset`s, which are now applied to the stored `\parbox` (named `\tmpbox`) rather than to the original argument itself.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

%%% Load packages
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%%% Define special box
% \specialbox{<rule width>}{<rule length hori>}{<rule length vert>}{<distance from text>}{<text>}
\newcommand{\specialbox}[5]{%
\savestack\tmpbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-#4-#4-#1-#1}{%
  \vspace{\dimexpr #1+#4} #5}}
\stackinset{l}{}{t}{}{ \rule{#2}{#1} }{%
\stackinset{l}{}{t}{}{ \rule{#1}{#3} }{%
\stackinset{r}{-#1-#4}{b}{}{ \rule{#2}{#1} }{%
\stackinset{r}{-#1-#4}{b}{-#1-#4}{ \rule{#1}{#3} }{%
  \hspace{\dimexpr #1+#4} \tmpbox}}}}}

%%% Define counter
\newcounter{myThm}
\setcounter{myThm}{0}
\renewcommand*{\themyThm}{\Roman{myThm}}
\newcommand{\mythm}{ \refstepcounter{myThm} {\bfseries Theorem \themyThm.} }

\begin{document}

\specialbox{1.5pt}{35pt}{35pt}{10pt}{%
\mythm \\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. 
\begin{align}\label{eq}
\dot{x}(t) = f\big( t,x(t) \big)
\end{align}
Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. 
}

\vspace{30pt}

\specialbox{1.5pt}{35pt}{35pt}{10pt}{%
\mythm \\
Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus.
\begin{align}\label{eq}
\dot{y}(t) = g\big( t,y(t) \big)
\end{align}
Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, that's it then. That's the answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hey wait, it's you! Haha. Thanks for the original design!

Comment: @StevenHorstink You are welcome!

Comment: @StevenHorstink You might want to thank the package developer, as well: https://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine  8^)

Comment: I suppose I should yes haha. His name is also Steven, by any chance?